# Unable to Evict Cache every 60 seconds using TTL config in Hazelcast

Tags: spring-boot, caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

```
@Bean
public Config cacheConfig() {

    Map<String, MapConfig> mapConfigs = new HashMap<>();

    EvictionConfig evictionConfig = new EvictionConfig();
    evictionConfig.setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LFU);
    evictionConfig.setSize(10);

    MapConfig widgetMapConfig = new MapConfig();
    widgetMapConfig.setBackupCount(1);
    widgetMapConfig.setName("widget");
    widgetMapConfig.setMaxIdleSeconds(60);
    widgetMapConfig.setTimeToLiveSeconds(60);
    widgetMapConfig.setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.BINARY);
    widgetMapConfig.setEvictionConfig(evictionConfig);

    mapConfigs.put("widget-Map", widgetMapConfig);

    Config programmaticConfig = new Config();
    programmaticConfig.setMapConfigs(mapConfigs);
    return programmaticConfig;

}
```

Above Is the config and Cache is not getting evicted when its not being used for 60 seconds. Can Someone help me on this. I want to Evict based on TTL config

Comment: if you are using 3.11+, you might want to use [CacheConfig](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/config/CacheConfig.html) instead of MapConfig. I had similar issues where the MapConfig didn't really create the cache for me.

Comment: Hi Avinash R, Im using 4.0+ I'm able to Cache Data and also Evict Data with MapConfig  during Method calls but when the Cache Expires based on the Max idle time and Time to live config, It should automatically be evicted which is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Core Hazelcast Module version form 4.0.2 to 4.2.4 and It started working for me. I would suggest anyone integrating Hazelcast with Springboot to look after the Release Date and choose the versions accordingly when you know your configuration are up to the mark as suggested in Hazelcast Official Documentation.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hazelcast/hazelcast -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
    **<version>4.2.4</version>**
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Version number should not have any implication on eviction. Once the entries are expired, they may remain in the JVM until they are garbage collected. The best way to check if entries are correctly expired and evicted is either do a map.size or use Management Center.
Do note that map.size is a very expensive distributed operation.